# Why my react native debugger is not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-native, react-native-ios

The react-native debugger was working perfectly fine for the very first time. But later on, when I opened my pc and tried to run my current project, the debugger was not working. I tried everything on my own up to the extent but was totally frustrated with this issue. Cleared my node modules for several times, thought that the error was with the version of node and installed several old versions of node but all my efforts went on vain. At last, I am here seeking help from all the react-native experts out there. Hope you will resolve my problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the guideline before Answer a question here.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure it is enabled JS debugging on the device is enabled.
2. Close the app on the phone but make sure the local server is running.
3. Manually open Chrome and go to link: http://localhost:19001/debugger-ui
4. Be sure to change the port to the correct one for you.
5. Once the debugger opens, open the app on the device.

I had a same issue yesterday and this fixed it for me.  Just had to open the debugger first then run the app.

Comment: Tried, but the result is same.Thank you for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

Fistly check if you have enabled the debugging mode in your app, if not then ctrl+m and enable 'remote JS debugging'. If your app is in debugging mode and still you cant find the debugger check all the tabs of your browser is open, it must be open somewhere (this happens in mac).

Comment: Sorry, bro. That was the first thing that I had tried.

Answer (score 1):

Got the error after I created a new project.

In podfile change `:hermes_enabled => true`

to

`:hermes_enabled => false`

then `pod install` .

resolves the problem. .

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your expo object in app.json file

```
"jsEngine": "jsc",
```